# What is the easiest way to validate a geoJson server response?

Tags: java, node.js, docker, geojson

I have a REST server that provides geoJson responses. Due to some format issues I want to integrate a geoJson validation into my integration tests.

What is the easiest way to implement that?

My available tech stack is Java, node.js, docker. I have no chance to use an online service for that task.

Answer (score 1):

[geojsonhint](https://github.com/mapbox/geojsonhint) is a relatively lightweight GeoJSON linter in JavaScript.